# How can I add raw input to a jupyter cell avoiding escaped quotes vs. quotes as input?

Tags: python, string, escaping, jupyter, quotes

I want to be able to add raw input to a jupyter cell. This is something I normally would have no problem doing such as:

```
raw_data='''
some lengthy raw input I 'want' to "process"
'''
```

Everything works well, and I keep all quotes and double quotes:

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, when I try e.g.

```
raw_data='''
this input has quotes: ["]
it unfortunately also has escaped quotes: [\"], and they end up exactly the same
'''
```

I loose the escaped quotes:

[image]

I know I could replace `\` with e.g. `\\` in my input, but am looking for a solution that
would allow me to copy-paste the exact raw input to jupyter and have it work...

Essentially it bogs my mind that in python `'''"'''` and `'''\"'''` seem to be *exactly* the same....

Comment: Did you consider raw strings for your raw data? `raw_data = r'''...`

Comment: It shouldn't be so bizarre that they're the same: `\t` and `\n` and lots of other values that start with backslashes are special (when not using raw strings), and when something _isn't_ in that set, `\<that>` just evaluates to `<that>` (though I'd argue that it _should_ be an outright syntax error; "[errors should never pass silently](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)", after all). If you want a literal backslash in a non-raw string, it's written as two backslashes... as you know, though I'm not clear why it's surprising.

Comment: @wovano Wow! you just blew my mind! :) I new about `b` and `f` but had no clue about `r`!  That is the answer...

Comment: And there's also `u`, but that has become pretty useless since Python 3 ;-)